# In what language was MSDOS originally written?

Tags: c, dos

In what language was MSDOS originally written in?

The [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS-DOS) implies either C, QBasic or Pascal, but:

- C was invented to write UNIX, so I don't believe it was used to write MSDOS
- Pascal seems popular to teach programming, but not really popular to write Operating systems in
- QBasic didn't seem to be very popular for Operating Systems at the time MSDOS was developed (or was *BASIC ever very popular to write Operating Systems in it?)

Except these three languages there is also Assembly, but I assume that Microsoft already switched from Assembly to a "higher" level language?

Since C was originally invented for UNIX, I still wouldn't think Microsoft is using C... although the Microsoft API is written in C (I find this kind-of oxymoronic, actually).

Can anyone enlighten me on this topic?

Comment: "C was invented to write UNIX, so I don't believe it was used to write MSDOS" - what are you talking about?

Comment: @Snake Plissken: read up on the History of C.

Comment: By "Microsoft API", I assume you mean the Windows API, which was written in C. The MS-DOS API was very different. You would load the processor registers with your parameters and execute a software interrupt to actually make the call.

Comment: There are plenty of good answers, but simply: Back then, most high-performance PC software was written in assembly. Why do you think they even wanted to switch to a high-level language?

Comment: I really have no idea at all what you mean. Xenix, Microsoft's version of Unix, predated MS-DOS.

Comment: @Ferruccio: Yes, the "current" Windows API. Unfortunately most links to the MSDOS Api documentation seem dead, so that's one of the reason I came up with this question. @Potatoswatter: absolutely, and I find it still impressive how they managed to write useful applications with something like assembly

Comment: @nake Plissken: didn't know about Xenix, sorry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://answers.google.com/answers/threadview?id=197874

> Since CP/M was written in FORTRAN and
>   QDOS was based on CP/M, does it mean
>   that QDOS and MS-DOS were written in
>   FORTRAN? According to our next
>   article, written by Tim Patterson
>   himself, the assembly language used by
>   Seattle Computer Products wasn't
>   FORTRAN but was built in-house since
>   it was the only thing available to
>   them at that time.
>
> "The last design requirement was that
>   MS-DOS be written in assembly
>   language. While this characteristic
>   does help meet the need for speed and
>   efficiency, the reason for including
>   it is much more basic. The only 8086
>   software-development tools available
>   to Seattle Computer at that time were
>   an assembler that ran on the Z80 under
>   CP/M and a monitor/debugger that fit
>   into a 2K-byte EPROM (erasable
>   programmable read-only memory). Both
>   of these tools had been developed in
>   house."
>
> "An Inside Look at MS-DOS"
>   http://www.patersontech.com/Dos/Byte/InsideDos.htm

Comment: CP/M was no more written in FORTRAN than it was  written in Chinese.  And FORTRAN is not an assembly language.Don't you just love the mounds of crap you can find on the internet if you look.

Comment: And this is exactly what the citation says: MS-DOS was written in assembly, with an in house developed toolchain working on the Z80 under CP/M

Comment: So... MSDOS was written in FORTRAN? I'm afraid I've misunderstood that somehow... :(

But then again it would have been silly to write MSDOS in assembly if the Machine where MSDOS was developed on was written in a higher language

Comment: @tonio: I didn't mind reading the article yet, but thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @zalew - When I was writing code for CP/M around 1983/4 I used 8080 Assembler. There is NO WAY that CP/M was written in Fortran.

Comment: I, too, wrote code for CP/M in 1980-1983, most of it in assembly language (8080). I also had a Forth system for my CP/M, but the core applications provided by Digital Research were all written in 8080 assembler, as far as I know. The of the main driving forces was memory size, and I don't think any of the FORTRAN compilers of the time could produce compact enough code.

Comment: @Ralph We had, and used, a Fortran compiler for our CP/M system. Too long ago to recall much about it though !

Comment: CP/M was definitely not implemented in Fortran. It was implemented in PL/M and assembly language. Both the CP/M OS and the PL/M language were developed by Gary Kildall. The source cited in this answer also implies that Fortran is an assembly language. Fortran is not and has never been an assembly language. MS-DOS, PC-DOS, 86-DOS (aka QDOS) were all originally implemented in Intel 8086 assembly language. Although Fortran compilers were available for MS-DOS, they were never used to implement MS-DOS.

Answer (score 8):

Well, MS-DOS was originally a renamed 86-DOS, and 86-DOS was written in assembly if I'm not mistaken, so that would make ASM the original language for MS-DOS as well.

Comment: Actually, it was originally called QDOS (quick and dirty operating system) and it was written in assembly language.

Comment: QDOS was the original name. 86-DOS was the commercial name.

Answer (score 3):

As stated on http://www.patersontech.com/Dos/Byte/InsideDos.htm

"The last design requirement was that MS-DOS be written in assembly language."

(Note that *alot* of appllications, not just operating system parts, were written in assembly back then.)

Answer (score 2):

See the [timeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_x86_DOS_operating_systems)

- [Assembler source](http://www.86dos.org/downloads/86DOS_FILES.ZIP) of 86DOS
- [Documentation](http://www.patersontech.com/Dos/Manuals.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the links! It's very interesting to see how an Operating system was implemented back then.

Answer (score 1):

Unix pre-dates MS-DOS, so that's not an impediment for it to be programmed en C. But I'd go for the assembly for most parts at least...

Comment: True, especially since the WINAPI is written in C as well. maybe it was just the common stereotype of "Unix/Linux vs. Windows" thingy that led me believing that Microsoft maybe just tried to avoid anything remotely UNIxish :P

Comment: @nebukadnezzar Microsoft used be a UNIX vendor - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenix

Comment: And Windows was originally developed on Xenix.

Comment: @neil Butterworth: Interesting Link, I didn't know Microsoft used to develope a UNIX flavoured Operating system

Comment: Windows 1, 2, 3.x and 95 were all written in assembler of the x86 variety (at least everything on the operating system side of the Win16/32 API was). That probably means that Windows 98 and Me were also written in assembler.

Comment: @JeremyP I find it difficult to believe that Windows 95 (or even more 98 and Me) were written in assembler language!

Comment: It's true.  The kernel and GDI and device drivers and so on were written in assembler.  The userland tools (like notepad) were of course written in C.  In fact the GDI was 95% identical to the GDI in Windows 3.1 in spite of the fact that it was 16 bit code.

Comment: My source is my copy of this book:

http://www.amazon.com/Systems-Programming-Windows-Microsoft-Progamming/dp/1556159498/ref=pd_sim_b_2

Comment: @JeremyP :-O (that would explain some things about stability, though xD)

Answer (score 0):

If you look for MS-DOS on some websites, you can find the version 6 with the source code included. It was written in Assembler and there's no C code at all. All the utilities, kernel, and even installer was written in assembler.

And regarding Windows, it has a lot of assembly language on it but some parts where writting in C and then C++.